# Прикрепить контроллер к FXML не через сам FXML

Tags: java, javafx

Собственно, есть у меня один FXML, к которому я, в зависимости от ситуации, хочу применять один из двух контроллеров, так что вариант с указанием оного в самом FXML не проходит. Можно конечно создать 2 одинаковых окна и дать каждому по контроллеру, но мне эта идея не особо по душе. Есть какой-то способ подключить контроллер к FXML'у в самом коде?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
loader.setController(new MyController());
loader.setLocation(Main.class.getResource("myFxml.fxml"));
```